# SQLiteOpenHelper switching database version

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to switch from different database versions. However, the application keeps crashing when I try to access lower database version when my recent access was a higher database version.

Here is the code

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 46;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("What does ICT stands for?","Individual Computing Techniques", "Information Computer Technology", "Information Computer Tutorial", "Information Computer Technology");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("Information Technology is also classified as the Science and Art of?", "Recording and Storage", "Past Time", "Information", "Recording and Storage");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("Based on the lesson, what are the things that you might experience when interacting with other people in the internet?","Free load", "Time Leisure","Cyber Bullying", "Cyber Bullying" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("What are the things you need to consider before turning off the computer?", "Make sure to save all your work", "Make sure to log out your account", "Leave a file open","Make sure to log out your account");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("Password must be?","Easy to guess","Easy to remember","Unique and hard to guess by other people","Unique and hard to guess by other people");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
```

Now, I have 5 java file of these and each have a different database version. When Im switching databases the application keeps crashing. Is there anyway to fix this?

Here is the logcat

```
03-31 22:45:20.793 25098-25098/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer, PID: 25098
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer/com.android.pet.view.QuizActivity1}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 46 to 45
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 46 to 45
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
   at com.android.pet.view.DbHelper1.getAllQuestions(DbHelper1.java:80)
   at com.android.pet.view.QuizActivity1.onCreate(QuizActivity1.java:35)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Can you show the logcat? And why do you have different database versions?

Comment: Obviously, because default implementation of `SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade` does it and you didn't override this method...

Comment: @cricket_007 Already updated. Its because I'am storing questions to my database

Comment: @Selvin Thank you for your response, However where would I put SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade on my code?

Comment: You don't need to update the database version if you add new questions to your database. You can just insert them into the existing table(s). The only reason you should update the database version is if you add or alter any existing tables.

Comment: @cricket_007 Here is the thing, I'am trying to create 5 quizzes. and those 5 quizzes needs their own unique set of questions, so I created 5 more databases and then, for me to be able to get the right database, I changed the database version.

Comment: I would just store a quiz id with each of the questions, then use `SELECT * FROM questions WHERE quiz_id = 1`, for example, to get the questions for  Quiz 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To downgrade a SQLite DB version in Android uou need to override the `onDowngrade(...)` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. Like you have your `onUpgrade(...)` method:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
...
}
```

add below it the downgrade method

```
@Override
public void onDowngrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// your DB dowgrade code
}
```

But you ure using a database in a wrong wrong. Do not create a new DB file for every quiz and their questions. You only need one DB for everything. Do not even create multiple tables for your quizzes. All quizzes belong into one table and all questions belong to one another table. Google some database basics...